# Nginx : Serve JPG images from different root and location

Tags: nginx

I have 3 different stockage area : "avatars" , "articles", "trends" where I store my images.

I want to "link" the URL "/trends/123.jpg" to trends folder , "/avatars/23.jpg" to avatar and so on.

Configuration 1:

```
server
{
    listen 8089;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www;

    location /trends/
    {
            alias  /var/storage/hottrend/;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|gif|png|jpg)
    {
            add_header Cache-control "public";
            access_log   off;
            expires      90d;
    }
}
```

Configuration 1 : "GET /trends/123.jpg" never match /trends/ location, why ?

Configuration 2:

```
server
{
    listen 8089;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www;

    location ~ ^/trends/(.*)\.jpg$
    {
            rewrite ^/trends/(.*)$ /$1 break;

            root  /var/storage/hottrend;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|gif|png|jpg)
    {
            add_header Cache-control "public";
            access_log   off;
            expires      90d;
    }
}
```

Configuration 2: The last rule with the caching stuff is not matched. What is the best approach to server JPG files from different location/root ?

Comment: There are a number of reasons that location might not match. Could you list the other locations (their content isn't needed)?

Comment: You can also get the desired effect using a symbolic link such as `trends -> /var/storage/trends`, since nginx follows symbolic links.

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé I dont want to use symbolic link, because all the code must run on different "environnements". (In despite this is the easiest solution;-(

Comment: There isn't enough information in a single `location` entry to determine why it isn't working, as the context is very important. However, if you can post a full example of your nginx configuration, I will examine it for you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The two configurations have different but related problems.  The two issues are:

1. the order in locations are matched; and
2. what happens when a location is matched.

I'll first explain how it works, and then I'll address your configurations.

**How it works**

*Location matching*

You can find the details on this [nginx wiki page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location), but I have always found the wording to be confusing.  (It mixes implementation details in the description of behaviour.)  What it means is that locations are matched in the following order:

1. exact matches like `location = /robots.txt`
2. eager non-regex prefixes like `location ^~ /trends/`
3. regex matches like `location ~* \.(jpg|png)`, or case-sensitive `location ~ \.(jpg|png)`
4. lazy non-regex prefixes like `location /trends/` or `location /`

If multiple regular expressions match, then the first match beats the others.  If multiple non-regex prefix match, I think it selects the most specific match -- I'll check this and update.

*Location behaviour*

A matching location is responsible for serving the designated content.  It is also responsible for providing cache-control headers and so on.  You can have a location that matches particular URL patterns to apply specific headers, but that location must also serve the content.  If it cannot serve the content, you will most likely get an 404 error -- it won't look for other matching locations.

Lastly, be extra careful if you have a rewrite within a location.  An internal redirect can happen earlier than some directives, in which case, those directive may not apply before the redirect causes the locations to be searched again.

**Configuration 1**

Your trends location is a lazy non-regex prefix, so it would only match if the regex location fails to match.  You can fix this by using an eager non-regex match, such as

```
location ^~ /trends {
    ...
}
```

However, doing so will highlight the other configuration problem.

**Configuration 2**

You have two locations that could potentially match jpg files.  Only one will succeed.  If the first matches, then the cache control of the second location won't be applied.  If the second matches, then the alias won't take effect.

The fix is to make sure that all directives needed are applied within the location that matches.  You can either be explicit in one file, such as

```
location ^~ /trends
{
    alias /var/storage/hottrend;

    add_header Cache-control "public";
    access_log   off;
    expires      90d;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|gif|png|jpg)
{
    add_header Cache-control "public";
    access_log   off;
    expires      90d;
}
```

The neater solution for managing directives that must be applied to several locations is to factor those details into another file, and then `include` it at both locations.  (Mohammad AbuShady did so in his example.)  Something like this:

```
# Inside your main .conf
location ^~ /trends
{
    alias /var/storage/hottrend;
    include image-headers.conf;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|gif|png|jpg)
{
    include image-headers.conf;
}

# Inside image-headers.conf
add_header Cache-control "public";
access_log   off;
expires      90d;
```

Comment: Thanks for having taken the time to make a real explanation, do you know a good blog or doc where I can improve my nginx?

Comment: @ThomasDecaux You are welcome. The wiki is the best current source of information, but it needs careful reading. One can also occasionally get useful information from the change logs.

Answer (score 5):

well I don't usually use alias but I think this is a good example to use alias for, you can put your caching settings inside `/etc/nginx/image_caching.conf`. If `trends` is only used for images i would not try to complicate the regex and assume that it always has images

```
location /trends {
    alias /var/storage/trends;
    include /etc/nginx/image_caching.conf;
}
```

And for your example config, you should have not added `/trends` inside `root /var/storage/trends;` because it's already used in the location, so i think it would show `404` becuase it's looking for `/var/storage/trends/trends/123.jpg`

Comment: Thomas combines a `rewrite` with `root`, which doesn't need fixing -- it will have the same effect as the solution with `alias`. However, he says it isn't working, so there must be something in the surrounding config that takes priority over this `location`.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to include the conf for each location matching JPG files, I cannot have another rule matching all static files (JPG,CSS,JS...) to do the caching stuff instead?

Comment: about the edited question config1, move the 2nd location inside the 1st location, see if that works, or if `trends` is just used for images then just merge the 2 locations into 1

Answer (score 0):

Nginx checks locations defined as regular expressions in the order in which they appear in the configuration file and uses the location with the first matching expression.

Therefore, you should make sure `location ~\.jpg$` appears before any other locations defined as regular expressions