# How to insert image in maintenance page using Nginx server

Tags: nginx

This is nginx configuration page.what code i have to change to get an image on maintenance html page.

---

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.10.10.72;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/fa/timesheet;
    }

    location / {
        if ($remote_addr != 10.10.10.120) {
            return 503;
        }

        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/fa/timesheet/timesheet.sock;
    }

    #Error pages.
    error_page 503 /maintenance.html;
    location = /maintenance.html {
        root  /home/fa/timesheet ;
    }
}
```

My Maintenance HTML page is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">
    <h1 style="color:#33B2FF;">Timesheet has gone for time travel..... will be back with more users :)</h1>
    <h1 style="color:#83A1B4;">Please visit later.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have to insert an image on it. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put all your all custom html and images in a directory **maintenance**

**`/home/fa`**

```
maintenance/maintenance.html
maintenance/maintenance.png
```

Put image tag in your **maintenance.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">
    <h1 style="color:#33B2FF;">Timesheet has gone for time travel..... will be back with more users :)</h1>
    <h1 style="color:#83A1B4;">Please visit later.</h1>
    <img src="maintenance.png" alt="maintenance" height="200" width="200">
  </body>
</html>
```

And change this lines in your **nginx.conf**:

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /maintenance.html;
location = /maintenance.html {
  root  /home/fa/maintenance_pages;
}
location = /image.png {
  root home/fa/maintenance_pages;
}
```

And if you have problem in rendering image types read this link also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19111990/6107715

Comment: This won't work as the 503 will be returned when the image is requested